# Subquery Fails even after distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, subquery, case

Here is my code that I am getting stumped on

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            JC11.JOB_NUMB
            ,CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, JC10.RDAT_SHIPPED +5843, 0), 1) AS [DATE SHIPPED]
            ,JC11.PROD_CODE
            ,SUM(CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB) AS [SALE PRICE]
            ,(SELECT SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_COSTS AS MONEY)) FROM JC20 WHERE JC20.JOB_NUMB = JC11.JOB_NUMB AND JC20.TRANS_CODE = 'O') AS [OSP COST]
            ,(SELECT DISTINCT
                    CASE 
                    WHEN JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MAJOR + JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MINOR = 100.00 THEN SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_TIME AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC20.JOB_NUMB) * CC10.AI_RATE 
                    WHEN JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MAJOR + JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MINOR = 100.01 THEN SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_TIME AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC20.JOB_NUMB) * CC10.AI_RATE 
                    WHEN JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MAJOR + JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MINOR = 100.07 THEN SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_TIME AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC20.JOB_NUMB) * CC10.AI_RATE 
                ELSE 0 END

                FROM JC20 
                JOIN CC10 ON JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MAJOR + JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MINOR = CC10.CCNTR_NUMB
                LEFT OUTER JOIN JC11 ON JC20.JOB_NUMB = JC11.JOB_NUMB


                WHERE JC20.JOB_NUMB = JC11.JOB_NUMB AND JC20.TRANS_CODE = 'L' AND JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MAJOR + JC20.CCNTR_NUMB_MINOR = CC10.CCNTR_NUMB
            ) AS [LABOR COST]


        FROM JC11
            LEFT OUTER JOIN JC10 ON JC10.JOB_NUMB = JC11.JOB_NUMB
            LEFT OUTER JOIN REPORTING.DBO.dimDate AS DIMDATE ON CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, JC10.RDAT_SHIPPED +5843, 0), 112) = dimdate.DateId



        WHERE
            DIMDATE.IsCurrentYear = 1
            and JC11.PROD_CODE = 100
```

Without the subquery it runs great but when the subquery is uncommented it is giving me the error about the subquery returning more than 1 value. I am confident that the query runs on it's own and brings back the correct row data. I am attempting to show cost by two different nmeasures, I achieved the first but this error has me stumped. In my jc20 table there will be multiple times for the same job which is why I used sum. Would it be better to group within the subquery? Is there a better way to write this subquery?

Comment: Any chance you could create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to recreate the problem?

Comment: you could do SELECT TOP 1 in the subquery, instead of SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: I see no inherent reason to suppose that your (second) subquery would return only one *row*, though each row it returns will have only one *column*.  Which row do you want?

Comment: Also, it's pretty pointless for your subquery to perform an outer join, but then filter out all the results that would not have appeared in an inner join.

Comment: Furthermore, it's horrible to have cost center numbers split over two columns in some tables but combined in the same column in other tables.  If the two parts have independent significance then they should always be tabulated separately; otherwise they should always be tabulated jointly.

Comment: *Run the subquery itself and look at the result(s).*
Then fix your `join` / `where` clause or use a `sum` or `max`.
I'm pretty sure you don't want more than 1 result (because subquery).
The `distinct` is no guarantee for a single result.
The error says it all: `more than 1 value`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Both numbers do have significance when seperate but they also have significance when joined. ex. 206.01 would be setup for that costcenter while 206.02 would be run for that costcenter.

Comment: @MatthewJakachira If they have independent significance then they should be tabulated independently.  Period.  This is a normalization question, and somewhat an indexing issue.  That combined pairs have significance, too, is no reason to cram them into one column.